# Error occurred during initialization of boot layer java.lang.module.FindException: Module javatutos not found

Tags: java, eclipse, boot, modulenotfounderror

I installed `Java 7` while using eclipse ide but I wanted to learn functional programming so I had to download `Java 9` but I did not uninstall java 7 with a good manner and i had problems to set up java 9 in the ide so thie errors occurs whenever i try to run a program  look in the pic at the red thing in the project [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cB5uE.png)

it seems like there still some java 7 files remaining i don't know

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66855489/java-lang-module-findexception-module-not-found

Comment: You really shouldn't use Java 9 any more. Java 11 is the closest still-supported release and the minimum version for what you're exploring.

Comment: Delete your `module-info.java` file (if needed you can recreate it later via right-click on project and _Configure_). Maybe you also have to delete your launch configuration before trying again. As has already been said, Java 9 is outdated. Use a Java version with long term support: 8, 11, 17 or 21.